# Как работает библиотека DevIL (openIL)

Tags: c++, opengl

вообще я хочу использовать библиотеку DevIL для openGL . Что бы загружать картинки.. но как мне объяснили, сам openGL не загружает картинки, нужны стороние библиотеки.
Но во время изучения библиотеки я пришел к выводу что не знаю и не имею представления что библиотека делает с картинкой?
А именно вопрос такой эта библиотека выдает машинный код картинки? Я вообще хотел бы получить массив с количеством пикселей, цветов, и глубины? Что бы программист смог с этим разобраться?
Я же правильно понял?
Или она тупо выдает машинный код?
Или эта Библа не позволяет получить программисту сведения о ширине, высоте, разрешении?

Answer (score 1):

Не знаком с библиотекой DevIL, но скажу по поводу OpenGL.. OpenGL действительно не работает с "картинками", он работает с текстурами. Текстуры по факту это карта пикселей (mipmap), и некое описание как их отрисовать. Причём вариантов как их рисовать штук 10.

Попробуй начать с этих вот статей.

- https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture
- https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Textures

Будут вопросы, задавай.

Comment: Ну вот я хотел бы попробовать вывести с помощью библиотеки DevIL массив пикселей через cout... и посмотреть как это выглядит... Правда сейчас я ничего не понимаю... Там вроде пару функций, например ilLoadImage(); которая вроде как открывает фаил, еще есть функция привязка имен  ilBindImage(), по документации она должна вызываться раньше всех. Смотрел примеры но так и не понял, как вывести массив пикселей.